# In Javascript document.write does not display CSS in response

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I am sending a POST request from java script to PHP. In PHP page I get all contents form a specific URL through `file_get_contents("URL")` and replace just replace all text inside the tags and then save

```
`$Translated=$dom->saveHTML();`
```

Now I echo `$Translated` in response. In JavaScript first I empty the document with `document.write('');` and then write the translated page                              `document.write(Translated);` it works fine but the CSS and slider does not work with `document.write`. Is there is way in PHP to write or Replace text on specific URL directly?

Comment: don't use document.write, it's an idiosyncrasy, instead if you _have_ to work directly with replacing HTML you can do `document.body.innerHTML = Translated`.

Comment: In addition to @BenjaminGruenbaum, probably you have to re-attach all events en special components to the respective DOM elements. Those are all lost after your replace.

Comment: Thanks you all.. i did, however still having issue. kindly visit http://balkhistrategy.com/ this link. at the bottom you will find a drop down menue of language, please change the language and wait for 30 second. you will easily get what issue i have.